# Using sed to replace the first instance of an entire line beginning with string

Tags: bash, sed

I am attempting to write a bash script that will use sed to replace an entire line in a text file beginning with a given string, and I only want it to perform this replacement for the first match.

For example, in my text file I may have:

```
hair=brown
age=25
eyes=blue
age=35
weight=177
```

And I may want to simply replace the first occurrence of a line beginning with "age" with a different number without affecting the 2nd instance of age:

```
hair=brown
age=55
eyes=blue
age=35
weight=177
```

So far, I've come up with

```
sed -i "0,/^PATTERN/s/^PATTERN/PATTERN=XY/" test.txt
```

but this will only replace the string "age" itself rather than the entire line.  I've been trying to throw a "\c" in there somewhere to change the entire line but nothing is working so far.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how this can be resolved?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure someone will post a better approach, but the minimal change to your script is to write `sed -i "0,/^PATTERN/ s/^PATTERN=.*$/PATTERN=XY/" test.txt` (since `.*$` matches the rest of the line).

Comment: is it possible to rewrite solution using your example replacing line beginning with `AGE` with `AGE=55`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ruakh suggests, you can use

```
sed -i "0,/^PATTERN/ s/^PATTERN=.*$/PATTERN=XY/" test.txt
```

A shorter and less repetitive way of doing the same would be

```
sed -i '0,/^\(PATTERN=\).*/s//\1XY/' test.txt
```

which takes advantage of backreferences and the fact that not specifying a pattern in an s-expression will use the previously matched pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`0,...`-ranges only work in `GNU sed`. An alternative might be to use shell redirect with `sed`:

```
{ sed '/^\(PATTERN\).*/!n; s//\1VAL;q'; cat ;} < file
```

or use `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="LABEL" && !n++ {$2="VALUE"}1' FS=\\= OFS=\\= file
```